# Extracting Text from a Column of Table A and Inserting into Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 Tables - Raw_Data and Pivot. The E_MSG Column in Raw_Data contains a string of text in which I have provided a sample string for 4 entries below. I would like to filter out certain key words from E_MSG and insert the filtered key word into the 'Cause' Column in Pivot. Specifically, the key words I want to input into the pivot table are "Internet Outage", "Server Crash", and "Unknown Error" as seen below in the code.

How should I go about doing this?

I was thinking that it can be accomplished with a INSERT INTO statement followed by a NESTED Conditional inside of the WHERE Statement

Please note that I am new to SQL and still getting use to the syntax. Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE Raw_Data (BOT_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, E_MSG VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT Raw_Data VALUES(1, 'filler words 1234 Internet Outage');
INSERT Raw_Data VALUES(2, 'filler words 5678 Server Crash');
INSERT Raw_Data VALUES(3, 'filler words 1234 Internet Outage');
INSERT Raw_Data VALUES(4, 'filler words 9999 Unknown error');


CREATE TABLE Pivot (P_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Process VARCHAR(20), Cause 
VARCHAR(20));
INSERT Pivot VALUES(1, 'AutoLoan', NULL);
INSERT Pivot VALUES(2, 'TFSA', NULL);
INSERT Pivot VALUES(3, 'eSig', NULL);
INSERT Pivot VALUES(4, 'mFunds', NULL);
```

Comment: update  your question add  a proper data sample  and the expected  result  ..(both as tabular text)

Comment: We need to know what the long string looks like. Yes, you can use 
'Insert into table_name select .... from ....' after you alter the table to create the new column.

Comment: please provide some sample data from table A and sample text from there that you want to insert in table B

Comment: I apologize as it is my first time posting on stack overflow. Please let me know if the updated information that I have provided is enough.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what exactly you want to store in the `pivot` table? "*whatever follows the letters 'Internet Outage'*" would be empty, as those are the last words in the sample data, so nothing "follows" those letters

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
CharIndex('Internet Outage', rd.E_MSG) > 0
```

use this to test whether or not your string contains what you are looking for